# Inserting in my JPA using entity manager native query

Tags: jpa, entitymanager

I am trying to insert a data in my database, i am using JPA in my project.

This is what my bean looks like.

```
@PersistenceContext
EntityManager em;

    em.createNativeQuery("INSERT INTO testtable ('column1','column2') VALUES ('test1','test2')").executeUpdate();
```

myfacade:

```
@Stateless
public class TestFacade extends AbstractFacade<Test> {
    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "TEST2PU")
    private EntityManager em;

    @Override
    protected EntityManager getEntityManager() {
        return em;
    }

    public TestFacade() {
        super(Test.class);
    }
```

i get an error:

```
javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: executeUpdate is not supported for a Query object obtained through non-transactional access of a container-managed transactional EntityManager
```

and if i dont use `@PersistenceContext for EntityManager`

```
EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("TEST2PU");
EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
em.createNativeQuery("INSERT INTO testtable ('column1','column2') VALUES ('test1','test2')").executeUpdate();
```

this is my error:

```
javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: 
Exception Description: No externally managed transaction is currently active for this thread
```

note: really need to use native query for this.

Comment: This problem is not related with JSF at all.

Comment: did you start transaction ? or what are you using for transaction management ?

Answer (score 14):

You can do it using NativeQuery and its executeUpdate method:

```
String query = "insert into Employee values(1,?)";

em.createNativeQuery(query)
   .setParameter(1, "Tom")
   .executeUpdate();
```

Comment: how to get last inserted id using this query?

Comment: @KumaresanPerumal did you already found out? Also wondering whether that's possible

Comment: @Kumaresan Perumal
"insert into table (a, b) values ('a', 'b') returning id;"
Try using that in combination with getResultList() and postgresql.

Answer (score 9):

I had same problem. Here is solution.

```
EntityManager em = getEntityManager();
EntityTransaction et = em.getTransaction();
et.begin();
em.createNativeQuery("UPDATE ... ;").executeUpdate();
et.commit();
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use `createNativeQuery` to write a query specific to the database language.

```
String query = "INSERT INTO userinfo ( login, upassword, email, mobile, fax, dob)"
             + " VALUES ( :a, :b, :c, :d, :e, :f)"

em.createNativeQuery(query)
    .setParameter("a", objUser.getLogin())
    .setParameter("b", objUser.getUpassword())
    .setParameter("c", objUser.getEmail())
    .setParameter("d", objUser.getMobile())
    .setParameter("e", objUser.getFax())
    .setParameter("f", objUser.getDob())
    .executeUpdate();
```

Comment: Some explanations would significantly improve the quality of your answer.

Comment: how can we d this for bulk inserts

Answer (score 5):

Assuming you're using the container-managed `entityManager` (injected with `@PersistenceContext`) you just miss an `@Transactionnal` annotation above your TestFacade method.

Answer (score 0):

```
String query = "SELECT * FROM daily_clouser_report_summery b "
                + "WHERE operatorId='" + operatorId + "' AND "
                + "STR_TO_DATE(b.repDate, '%d-%m-%Y')"
                + "BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE('" + formattedDates + "', '%d-%m-%Y') AND STR_TO_DATE('" + formattedDates + "', '%d-%m-%Y');";
        SessionFactory sf = this.hibernateTemplate.getSessionFactory();
        EntityManager em = sf.createEntityManager();
        List<DailyClouserReportSummery> list = em.createNativeQuery(query, DailyClouserReportSummery.class).getResultList();
        return list;
```