# Pass SQL statement to JPA @Query

Tags: spring, jpa

Is there a way to pass the whole sql statement or a part of it to @Query annotation?

```java
@Modifying
@Query(value = "INSERT INTO my_table :query", nativeQuery = true)
@Transactional
void test(@Param("query") String query);
```

Comment: You can't execute INSERT that way. But what's your use case?

Comment: I need to make UPSERT into PostgreSQL. And some fields can be NULL in DAO, which cause error on inserting into column of some types, for instance, BIGINT and TIMESTAMP

Comment: But then you can not use JPA. Checkout the JdbcTemplate

Comment: It's a pity. Thank you for your comment

Comment: Why can't you simply use the Repository.save function?

Comment: @Daniellllll, in short - I need concurrent save & update, which is not possible that way.

Answer (score 1):

I think a viable option for you would be to use the entity manager, instead of the repository. You can do it using NativeQuery and its executeUpdate method. Please check:

[Inserting in my JPA using entity manager native query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16805224/inserting-in-my-jpa-using-entity-manager-native-query)